# jQuery Validate, changing rules on the fly

Tags: jquery-validate

I have been setting up my jQuery Validate rules in Javascript much like in this article:
http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/2/10/An-Introduction-to-jQuery-and-Form-Validation-2

I store the rules in a jsony object called validationRules, then I pass the rules when I invoke the Validate plugin:

```
$("#myForm").validate(validationRules);
```

Later, I'd like to programatically change values based on user interactions, like this:

```
validationRules.rules.Quantity.min=10;
```

even though the value is updated, Validate doesn't honor the new value. I also tried, re-invoking the plugin:

```
$("#myForm").validate(validationRules);
```

but that didn't help.

I can just talk directly to the plugin:

```
$("#Quantity").rules("add", {min: 10});
```

and it behaves as one would expect. So I will use that syntax to change rules on-the-fly, but could someone shed some light on how I can tell Validate to honor the updated rules in validationRules?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I have spent a lot of time trying to solve it. Finally I find a trick in the Validation Plugin creator´s GitHub account:

```
var $form       = $('#formId'),
    newRules    = {rules...},
    newMessages = {messages...};

$.each(newRules , function(key, value) {
    newRules [key] = $.validator.normalizeRule(value);
});
$.extend( $form.validate().settings.rules, newRules );
$.extend( $form.validate().settings.messages, newMessages );
```

I am not quite sure about the messages, I am using it right now and seems to work fine.
This is the link where you can read more about it:
https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/214